# SwiftUI - maxHeight: .infinity pushes VStack outside of safe area?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a body:

```
var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text(getGreeting())
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            Text("\("self.user.username")'s home")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Spacer()
        }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

I want the VStack to fill the whole height of the phone screen, which is why I added the frame:

```
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

It works on all phones with a notch (where the safe area is underneath the two status bars and reacts with the safe areas:

[image]

This is correct, however, on phones with out a notch (iPhone SE, iPhone 7/8 etc.):

[image]

Is this normal, or a bug? I do not have any modifiers that change the safe area bounds.

UPDATE:

If I remove the `.frame` modifier (as pawello2222 correctly said) I do not need both a spacer and a .frame, I still get this wrong result:

[image]

It still goes beyond, what should be, the safe area?

ALL CODE:

Main View:

```
struct Main: View {

    @State var showLoginScreen = false

    var body: some View {
        if(showLoginScreen){
            LoginView()
        }else{
            TabView(showLoginScreen:      $showLoginScreen).hiddenNavigationBarStyle()
        }
    }
 }
```

```
struct TabView: View {
    
    @State var index = 0
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var scheme
    @Binding var showLoginScreen: Bool
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            
            ZStack{
                Home(index: $index)
                    .opacity(self.index == 0 ? 1 : 0)
                    .animation(.spring())
                Control()
                    .opacity(self.index == 1 ? 1 : 0)
                    .animation(.spring())
                Account(showLoginScreen: $showLoginScreen)
                    .opacity(self.index == 2 ? 1 : 0)
                    .animation(.spring())
            }
            
            ZStack {
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .frame(height: 60)
                HStack{
                    Button(action: {
                        self.index = 0
                    }){
                        HStack(spacing: 6){
                            Image(systemName: "house")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)//index == 0 ? .white : .primary)
                            if self.index == 0{
                                Text("home")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .background(self.index == 0 ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)) : Color.clear)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                    }
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.index = 1
                    }){
                        HStack(spacing: 6){
                            Image(systemName: "text.justify")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)//index == 1 ? .white : .primary)
                            if self.index == 1{
                                Text("control")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .background(self.index == 1 ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)) : Color.clear)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                    }
                    
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.index = 2
                    }){
                        HStack(spacing: 6){
                            Image(systemName: "person")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)//index == 2 ? .white : .primary)
                            if self.index == 2{
                                Text("account")
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                        .background(self.index == 2 ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5568627715, green: 0.3529411852, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1)) : Color.clear)
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                    }
                }
                
                .padding(.horizontal, 25)
                .padding(.top, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom == 0 ? 20 : UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                .padding(.bottom, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom == 0 ? 20 : UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

It happens on all views (Home, Control, account), I'll just provide the Home View:

```
struct Home: View {

    @Binding var index: Int
    @EnvironmentObject var user: userData

    var body: some View{
            VStack{
                Text(getGreeting())
                    .font(.title)
                   .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                Text("\("self.user.username")'s home")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                Spacer()
            }
       // .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not in provided code, but rather in parent view. Would you show complete screen code?

Comment: @Asperi Please see edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the VStack to fill the whole height of the phone screen, which
> is why I added the frame

You already have a `Spacer` in your `VStack` which consumes all available space.

Which means your code will run fine without the `frame` modifier:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(getGreeting())
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        Text("\("self.user.username")'s home")
            .font(.subheadline)
            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        Spacer()
    }
    // .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // remove
}
```

Even without the `frame` modifier, your `VStack` has the same height as the screen (because of the `Spacer`).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I tried it both: without the frame modifier /without the Spacer(), see updated question.

Comment: @Nathan Is this your root view? Or do you have any parent view?

Comment: Please see edits, I've provided all the code involved.

Comment: @Nathan Why do you need these 2 lines: `.padding(.bottom, UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom == 0 ? 20 : UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets.bottom)` ? Try removing them.

Comment: I have that for the iPhone devices with swipe gesture as I wanted extra padding for the swipe home indicator, removing them does not do anything for screens with a home button.

Comment: @Nathan Try removing `.hiddenNavigationBarStyle()` as well.